# Pivot table and assign cell values

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-table, cell, variable-assignment

I am learning Javascript and I created a table that gives me averages over time that I am generating from MySQL. The output looks something like:

```
Time            C        W         T             C2         T2
00:00:00    5.8      22.4     12.3     18.8      1.9
00:15:00    7.5      21.4     13.3     16.6      2.5
00:30:00    6.2      16.1     10.9     10.9      2.1
00:45:00    12.8   14.2     7.0        12.1      4.3
```

I am basically pulling my data from a PHP file and then replace/splitting the data so do this. I split them into rows, add HTML and then chop them into cells and echo them out with HTML again. That part of my code looks like this:

```
        var lines = data.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").split("\n");
    var outPut = "<table class='timetable'>";
    outPut += "<tr><th>T</th><th>C</th><th>W</th><th>T</th><th>C2</th><th>T2</th></tr>";
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        outPut += "<tr>";
        var cells = lines[i].split("|");
        for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
            outPut += "<td>" + cells[j] + "</td>";
        }
        outPut += "</tr>";
    }
    outPut += "</table>";
    console.log("Cells!");

    $("#report").append(outPut);
    $("#report td:contains(':')").css("background-color", "#ae1036").css("color", "#FFFFFF");
```

I have a button that controls this function and adds the table (as many times as the user likes for comparison sake). That button is:

```
    <button type="button" onclick="generateReport();">Add Projection</button>
```

Then I have a button to clear the page:

```
    <button type="button" onclick="clearReport();">Clear</button>
```

What I am wanting to do is pivot my entire table so the time goes across the top. Also - with the MySQL output, if the average is 0 - no data is present and the time is skipped (00:45 to 02:30 for example). I need to include those zeroes. Also - I am going to need totals on the bottoms and sides of each of the cells. I know I am asking for a lot - but I just really need some direction with this - at this point, I'm not sure how to go about it.

The end product will look something like this:

```
                     00:00     00:15     00:30     00:45     01:00     01:15     01:30     01:45     02:00     02:15        Total
                     1.5          1.8          9.5         15.0        13.2       5.4          4.3          7.5          9.5         6.5             74.2
Totals:         1.5          1.8          9.5         15.0        13.2       5.4          4.3          7.5          9.5         6.5             74.2
```

And then when I apend again, It should be more like:

```
                     00:00     00:15     00:30     00:45     01:00     01:15     01:30     01:45     02:00     02:15        Total
                     1.5          1.8          9.5         15.0        13.2       5.4          4.3          7.5          9.5         6.5             74.2
                     1.1          1.2          9.3         15.0        13.2       5.1          4.3          7.4          9.6         6.8             72.0
Totals:         2.6          3.0          18.8       30.0        26.4      10.5        8.6          14.9        19.1      19.3           146.2
```

I thought maybe I could make the table headers and then assign each value to an array linked by the time as the primary key? But I don't see anything like that. I read that in JavaScript, objects are a loose collection of properties and values - essentially key/value pairs... So I am sure its something that I am not thinking of - having been in PHP land for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is a big edit*

You can test this solution on jsFiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/rqKUH/30/.  This solution assumes that there is a header row, a footer row that has spaces for totals, and the right most column for total.  These assumptions can easily be changed by changing the selectors.  You can also change summation to another function.

My table:

```
<table id="report">
<tr>
    <th >&nbsp;</th><th>H1</th><th >h2</th>
    <th >h3</th><th>Total</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td >R1</td><td>2</td><td>32</td><td>1</td><td ></td>
</tr>
<!-- rows removed for brevity -->
<tr>
    <td >R5</td><td>100</td><td>5</td><td>15</td><td ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td >Total</td><td ></td><td ></td><td ></td><td></td>
</tr>    
</table>
<button id="pivot">pivot</button>
```

Code:

```
    $('#pivot').click(function () {
        var saveElems = [],
           i = 0, j = 0, $tbl, $row, colMax = 0, rowMax;

        $tbl = $('#report');
        $('#report tr').each(function () {
            saveElems[i] = [];
            j = 0;
            $(this).children().each(function () {
                saveElems[i][j] = this;
                j++
            });
            i++;
        });

        rowMax = saveElems.length;
        for (var i = 0, il = rowMax; i < il; i++) {
            colMax = Math.max(colMax, saveElems[i].length);
        }
        $tbl.children().remove();

        for (var i = 0, il = colMax; i < il; i++) {
            $tbl.append($row = $('<tr />'));
            for (var j = 0, jl = rowMax; j < jl; j++) {
                if (saveElems[j][i]) $row.append(saveElems[j][i]);
            }
        }
        computeTotals();
    });

    function computeTotals() {
        var saveValues = [],
          i = 0, j = 0, cellValue, colValue, rowTotals = [], colTotals = [];

        $('#report tr').not(':first, :last').each(function () {
            saveValues[i] = [];
            j = 0;
            $(this).children().not(':first, :last').each(function () {
                saveValues[i][j] = this.innerHTML;
                j++
            });
            i++;
        });

        for (var k = 0, kl = saveValues.length; k < kl; k++) {
            rowTotals[k] = 0;
            for (var l = 0, ll = saveValues[k].length; l < ll; l++) {
                cellValue = parseFloat(saveValues[k][l]);
                colTotals[l] = cellValue + ((colValue = colTotals[l]) ? colValue : 0);
                rowTotals[k] = cellValue + rowTotals[k];
            }
        }

        i = 0;
        $('#report tr:not(:first, :last)').each(function() {
            $(this).children(':last').html(rowTotals[i]);
            i++;
        });

        i = 0;
        $('#report tr:last').children().not(':first, :last').each(function () {
            console.log(colTotals[i]);
            this.innerHTML = colTotals[i];
            i++;
        });
    }

    computeTotals();
```

Comment: I am not quite sure where to put this in the code even... I tried to auto pivot my table so I could start playing around with the code... But console says: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function.

Comment: I just updated it to include everything you need.  Play around with it in jsFiddle (I updated the link) until you get it.  I went way out there for this solution, so you figure out the rest and mark it as answered when you do.

Comment: I found out where to put this code - the pivot button is... mostly? working. Does this code require the table to have the same amount of cells horizontally and vertically? It seems to just go up to "1:00", cut everything else off and mark the cells that would normally be vertical as 'undefined'... I updated the jsFiddle that you so kindly made for me - to show you the error: http://jsfiddle.net/rqKUH/26/

Comment: This is supposed to be more of an 'automatic' thing... There will ultimately be no button. With that said - I'm still slightly unsure how to proceed... I really appreciate all of the effort that you put in so far!

Comment: You are excellent! I can't wait to see /how/ you're going to do this. I am sure I am going to learn a lot from it.

Comment: Hey - I've been looking at your code on http://jsfiddle.net/rqKUH/30/ I was able to remove some simple syntax errors in http://jsfiddle.net/rqKUH/31/. It appears to be working... I was wondering if you are still messing around with this - It doesnt seem to work for me in just a <script language="JavaScript"> </script>... Is there any way I can use this as is? Or any way I can assist?

Comment: I'm done with this.  It works fine for me.  I have the table, and the script tag below that.  If its above you might have to encase computeTotal in $(document).ready()

Comment: Well - you definitely have the right answer. I will try to use this example and apply it to my actual situation. Thank you so much! +right +1